# Structure initialization error: could not convert from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to structure

Tags: c++, c++11, structure, initializer-list

I have the following code:

```
struct Vec { double x=0, y=0, z=0; };

Vec orig = {1,2,3};
```

GCC 4.8.4 shows the following error:

```
error: could not convert ‘{1, 2, 3}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Vec’
 Vec orig = {1,2,3};
                  ^
```

When I change take away the equals sign

```
Vec orig {1,2,3};
```

there comes another error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Vec::Vec(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
 Vec orig {1,2,3};
                ^
```

How can I initialize the structure properly without creating a constructor?

Comment: Have you tried `struct Vec { double x, y, z; };`?

Comment: @john, yes, it compiles fine. But I also need to have a default initializator for the structure.

Comment: @user2513149 [Cannot duplicate](https://www.ideone.com/vbVcsG).  I think you need to get a more recent version of the compiler.

Comment: If you are restricted to a pre-C++14 compiler then you will either have to create a constructor, or remove the default member initializers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using c++11, but not yet c++14.

Once you provide *default member initializers*, the class is no longer an *aggregate*, and you cannot use *aggregate initialization*.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> ...
>
> - class type (typically, struct or union), that has
>
>   ...
>
>   - no default member initializers (until c++14)

Comment: Is this limitation only for C++11 or later versions as well?

Comment: Note: This was the case for C++11,  but is no longer true since C++14

Comment: Unfortunately, my GCC 4.8.4 supports only C++11. It seems a rather ridiculous limitation. But thank you anyway!

Comment: gcc 4.8.4 is five years old. The chances of a 2013-era compiler to fully support a C++ standard that won't officially exist for another year, are rather slim.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare variables to struct you maybe use

```
    Vec orig = {1,2,3};
    auto orig= new Vec;
    orig->x=1;
    orig->y=1;
    orig->z=1;
    cout<<orig->z;
```

and if you want declare array

```
    struct Vec { int arr[20]; };

    auto orig= new Vec{{1,2,3,4,5}};
    cout<< orig->arr[3] <<endl;
```